# XPATH indices different?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, mechanize

I am using Mechanize on Ruby, and noticed the following in my Ruby console:

```
1.9.3p194 :188 > testpage = Mechanize.new.get "http://www.sis.umd.edu/bin/soc?term=201208&crs=AGNR"
...
1.9.3p194 :184 > testpage.search("font[@face='arial,helvetica']").last.search("b[2]").text
 => "" 
1.9.3p194 :185 > testpage.search("font[@face='arial,helvetica']").last.search("b")[1].text
 => "Special Problems:\nSpecial Problems;"
```

Why is accessing the second `b` element in XPATH giving a difference result than accessing the second element of all Nokogiri `b` elements returned giving a different result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`search("b[2]")` means any `b` that is the second `b` relative to its
   parent element. It will be a NodeSet and it may have more than one element.

`search("b")[1]` means the second `b` that it finds. It will be either a Node or nil.

Comment: What does "second b relative to it's parent" mean, and how could there be more than one second b that it finds?

Comment: e.g. in `<a><b/><b/></a> <a><b/><b/><b/></a>` there are two first and two second b elements relative to their a, but only one third element

Comment: Ohhhh it all makes sense now! Thank you so much!